# Scan Packages from a submodule in a springBoot application

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have a springBoot application which has got multiple subModules.

the submodules are imported in `POM` with module tag

I need to autowire an interface that exists in one of the submodules.

what can I do other than :

1. annotate the `inteface` with `@component`
2. make the package of the `interface` in `@componentScan(basePackages={"blablaPackage"})`

even though I did all of that i still get this error

> NoSuchBeanDefinitionException
>   consider defining bean with type bla bla bla .

Comment: Unclear. Autowire where? From one submodule to another? Then you must add a dependency on the module where interface is placed

Comment: yes ofcourse the dependency is placed ! otherwise the type wont be known and yes i want to autowire an interface belonging to module 1 into another module 2 ( note that module 2 imports the dependency module 1)

Answer (score 0):

Im guessing you want all implemented classes to be autowired?

Without firing up an ide to try it out Im pretty sure you cant do that.

Try adding @Component to the concrete class and see if that works.